# Help understaning LTL formulae

Tags: logic, formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic

I am studying Software Engineering and I have different LTL formulas for which I have to determine if they are valid, unsatisfiable or neither.

Here are the formulas :

1. (<>[]p ∧ <>[]q) → <>[](p ∧ q)
2. ([]<>p ∧ []<>q) → []<>(p ∧ q)
3. ([]<>p) ∨ ([]<>¬p)
4. ([](p → <>q)) → (p → <>q)
5. ([]false) → (<>false)

I don't really understand these formulas and I don't know how to proceed. Should I build a Büchi Automaton ? What are the steps to solve this kind of question ?

Comment: You should start by understanding the formulas. For this, consult any reference on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a Büchi automaton, but that might be harder than just understanding the formulas.

Let's consider the first formula:
$$(\diamond\square p \wedge \diamond \square q)\to\diamond\square(p\wedge q)$$
In the left hand side of the "$\to$", consider the expression $\diamond\square p$, which reads "eventually always $p$".
Thus, the entire left hand side of the "$\to$" says that eventuall $p$ will hold forever, and eventually $q$ will hold forever.

The right hand side says that both $p$ and $q$ will eventually hold forever.

This formula is valid, since if we wait long enough, then both $p$ will hold forever and $q$ will hold forever, meaning $p\wedge q$ will hold forever (eventually).

Try to work out the rest using similar considerations.